# Creating a Sum of numbers app with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, do-while

I'm working throught an excercise from a book. The result should be to create an application that uses a prompt method to get the user entry that can be from 1 to 100. Then the app adds all the numbers from 1 up until the user's entry and displays the sum of numbers. 
If the user entry is 5, then the app adds 1,2,3,4 and 5 giving a total of 15.

I have an issues: 
I need to create a `do-while` loop so that if the entry is not a valid number, it prompts the user again until is it. It seems that even if the input is a valid number, this error message pops up at the end. In other words the input returns as `NaN`.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sum the Numbers</title>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>  
    <script>
        alert("Sum the Numbers from 1 through entry");

        var sumOfNumbers = 0;
        var entry = prompt("Enter top number to sum", 5);
            entry = parseInt(entry); 
            console.log(entry);

        for (i = 1; i <= entry; i++) {
            sumOfNumbers += i;
        }
        alert("The sum total is "+ sumOfNumbers);

        do {
            if (isNaN(entry) || entry < 1 || entry > 100); {
            }
            alert("Error, please enter a valid number from 1 to 100");
        }
        while (isNaN(entry) || entry < 1 || entry > 100);

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <h1>This page is displayed after the JavaScript is executed</h1>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Your alert is not within the if-statement, so it will always run, regardless of the input. I do not understand why you have the same statement twice as this would render your entire while loop useless. You also have a syntax error behind the if statement in your do-while loop. There should not be a `;` behind the closing bracket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this code doesn't work as expected is because your do-while loop doesn't really help you retrieve a valid number.

Instead, if your do-while loop looked like:

```
do {
// collect number from user and store in variable 'entry'
// I'll let you write the actual code, for the sake of your learning exercise
}
while (isNan(parseInt(entry)) || entry < 1 || entry > 100);
```

... the do-while would repeatedly prompt the user until they have a valid number between 1 and 100. Then, below the do-while loop, you can process the sumOfNumbers and display to the user -- since you know that only valid numbers were able to get past the do-while loop.

NOTE: you don't need the extra if() check inside the do... that's what the 'while' is for.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sumOfNumbers = 0;    
var entry;

do{
    entry = +prompt("Enter top number to sum", 5);
}while (!entry || entry < 1 || entry > 100)

for (i = 1; i <= entry; i++) {
    sumOfNumbers += i;
}

alert("The sum total is "+ sumOfNumbers);
```

You have to show the prompt till a correct number is entered. The `+` before the prompt makes the entered string an integer, if it isn't a valid number it becomes `NaN`.

The do-while loop you provided actually keeps alerting the error if the entry is false because you aren't able to change the entry and the if check doesn't do anything. Also a do-while loop is always executed, if you don't want it to execute the first time you have to use a while loop. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    `enter code here`<head>
    <title>JavaScript</title>
    
    
    
    
    
    <script>
    var again = "y";
    do{
    var sum = 0;
    var entry;
    
        do {
            var entry = prompt("Enter any top number to sum\n" + "from 1 through 100", 5);
    
                if (isNaN(parseInt(entry)) || entry < 1 || entry > 100){
    
                     alert("Error, please enter a valid number from 1 to 100");
    
                } 
    
        }while (isNaN(parseInt(entry)) || entry < 1 || entry > 100); 
        
            for(i = 1; i <= entry; i++){
        
                sum += i;
        
            }
    
    alert("The sum of numbers from 1 throught " + entry + " is " + sum);
    again = prompt("Repeat entries?", "y");
    }while(again == "y");
    
    
    
    </script>
    
    
    
    </head>
    <html>
```